# Hashmaps: What's the difference between a node map and a flat map?

Tags: c++, hashmap

What are the different types of hashtables and the difference between them?

I often see references to "node map" and "flat map" types. Abseil library has both implementations, but doesn't explain what the different use cases are, and neither does a Google search reveal any description.

Answer (score 6):

[Tip #136](https://abseil.io/tips/136) explains it pretty well.

In short: An Abseil flat map has a bucket array that directly stores map entries. A node map stores pointers to map entries. (Both types apparently use open addresing strategy.) Notably, in a flat map, even empty buckets take up space; in a node map, they only take up a pointer's worth of memory.

Finally, note that the term "flat map" is, especially outside of the C++ world, usually reserved for a function that collects results of applying a function to each element of a subsequence, a very different meaning.

Comment: Thanks, that helped, but I'm still confused. What if I were storing large objects and I don't care about pointer stability? Use a flat map of pointers, or a node map of the original objects? Also I saw the node map outperforming the flat map on the Robin hood hashtables benchmarks.

Comment: Actually, I was wrong. I will update the answer.

Comment: *outperformed for search